# Remove one, non-unique value from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update

Given this table in PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
   id int PRIMARY KEY
 , test_array text[]
);
```

With a row like:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, test_array)
VALUES (1 , '{A,A,A,B,B,B}');
```

How would I remove one single 'B' value?

I cannot use:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET test_array = array_remove(test_array, 'B')
WHERE id = 1;
```

as it removes *all* elements of value 'B'. I am just looking to remove a single element (say, the first one).

Any ideas?

Comment: see this question from DBA SE https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/delete-array-element-by-index

Comment: This is assuming I know the exact index of a string.   I would need a function where I can input the string, it would find the first index containing that string, and then remove that index from the array.

Comment: You just have to replace 'B' in the " position('B' " to the character/string you want to replace. Just as you would pass 'B' in your example function array_remove(test_array, 'B')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my old answer on dba.SE that you found and put to good use:

- [Delete array element by index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94642/3684)

You might take it one step further:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_remove_elem1(anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyarray LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1[:idx-1] || $1[idx+1:] FROM array_position($1, $2) idx';
```

This function takes the value of the element to remove as 2nd parameter. Using the polymorphic pseudo-type `anyelement` accordingly to make this work for any array type.

Then the `UPDATE` simply is:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    test_array = f_array_remove_elem1(test_array, 'B')
WHERE  id = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=24148a8e922df141057e50eeb7369fd2)*

While using my original function `f_array_remove_elem()` that takes the index position instead of the element value, you could do without a subquery:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    test_array = f_array_remove_elem(test_array, array_position(test_array, 'B'))
WHERE  id = 1;
```

Might even be a bit faster than my new function.
And note that the simpler version at the bottom of my old answer works for Postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after expanding on the information provided on this page (suggested by Sharon Ben Asher)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/delete-array-element-by-index

creating the function mentioned there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_remove_elem(anyarray, int)
RETURNS anyarray LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1[1:$2-1] || $1[$2+1:2147483647]';
```

and implementing array_position on top of this, the final statement for the example:

```
UPDATE test_table SET test_array = f_array_remove_elem(test_array, array_position(test_array, 'B')) WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Aside: Why the cast `test_array::text[]`. The columns already is `text[]`, isn't it?

Comment: Removed the unnecessary subquery and cast, thanks for the help

Comment: I buy a stray `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one

```
select SUBSTRING ( '{A,A,A,B,B,B}',1,position('B' in '{A,A,A,B,B,B}') -1)||SUBSTRING ('{A,A,A,B,B,B}',position('B' in '{A,A,A,B,B,B}')+1)
```

First find the position of B in the string, then get the substring until just before the first occurrence of B i.e '{A,A,A, then get the substring of the remaining string leaving the B i.e ,B,B}'