# Remove one, non-unique value from a 2d array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update

To expand on my answered question here:

[Remove one, non-unique value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992228/remove-one-non-unique-value-from-an-array)

Given this table in PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
   id int PRIMARY KEY
 , test_array text[][]
);
```

With a row like:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, test_array)
VALUES (1 , '{ {A,AA},{A,AB},{B,AA},{B,AB} }');
```

How would I remove an index from test_array:

a) matching the [0] value,

b) matching both the [0] and [1] values.

I am getting an exception when using array_position:

> searching for elements in multidimensional arrays is not supported

Also, how would an update query be constructed based on this matching?

I'm not sure that I can build a query as done in a 1d array.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to do that on a regular basis, you have chosen the wrong data model. Normalize your model and the delete gets as easy as `delete from ... where ..`.

Comment: Why is a data model wrong to have nested data?  I see the options as either parsing nested data or creating multiple extra tables/columns having to join and reference keys.   I understand from a possible SQL query perspective (as it is not simple), but parsing this kind of data in C# / Javascript etc. is quite easy.   If there is no feasible answer, then I can always fall back to a 1D array of JSON data, and parse it externally.

Comment: Because it violates the basic principles of normalisation. The manual [even has a warning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) regarding that: "*Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements*" - and deleting individual elements is essential the same as "searching"

Comment: I understand your thoughts on the matter. I am using a 2d array as means for a basic key/value pair.  As far as "regular basis", this is only in one specific column, I am not using it regularly throughout my DB.

Comment: A key/value pair is better done using hstore or JSONB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to normalize instead (in this instance, breaking the arrays into two tables with reference keys), per a_horse_with_no_name's recommendation.